# Fixed number Dynamic table row

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code which show dynamic table row . I want table will not show more than four rows . I don't need rows after fourth row . How can I edit this code.

Thanks to all

```
 $('#history').prepend('<tr><td>'+labordate+'</br>'+ formattedStart+'</td><td>'+lengthFormatted+'</td><td>'+timeBetweenFormatted+'</td></tr>')
```

Comment: show more code please.. JS? table?

Comment: I still dont understand your question. Do you want to loop the above line so that it prints four time?

Comment: Yes I want loop, and I want to print latest four data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
 if($('#history').find('tr').length < 5) {
        $('#history').prepend(''+labordate+''+ formattedStart+''+lengthFormatted+''+timeBetweenFormatted+'');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , but one more thing ,I need latest four data .

Comment: it depends on the server. update your query to get the data in ascending/descending order and when you are fetching, use this code.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
var tableDataCounter = 0 ;

if(tableDataCounter < 4)
{
    $('#history').prepend('<tr><td>'+labordate+'</br>'+ formattedStart+'</td><td>'+lengthFormatted+'</td><td>'+timeBetweenFormatted+'</td></tr>')
    tableDataCounter++;
}
```